# Class initialitation, notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsnotification

I have classes: `loginViewController`, `helloViewController`, `howAreYouViewController`. I also have a class `ActionsViewController`.

The first 3 classes are initialized when it is appropriative. I want to call some methods from `ActionsViewController` (but it not allocated and instantiated as ViewController).

I use `NSNotification`s, but as `ActionsViewController` is not show on the screen yet, my notifications are not registered. How to fix it?

UPDATE

for example full scenario is:

loginViewController ->  helloViewController (!)-> howAreYouViewController -> if user click some action go to ActionsViewController.

I want to run method '-(void)testMethod' from ActionsViewController in (!) via NSNotifications. In (!) ActionsViewController is not showed and as it I not initalise it.

Comment: Describe a full scenario. What is creating `ActionsViewController`, when and why? What are these notifications?

Comment: @Wain, for example full scenario is: loginViewController ->  helloViewController (!)-> howAreYouViewController -> if user click some action go to ActionsViewController. I want to run method '-(void)testMethod' from ActionsViewController in (!). In (!) ActionsViewController is not showed and as it I not initalise it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Seems like a strange requirement. Should you be passing some initialisation data instead...

Comment: @Wain, I do not want to duplicate my code and method that I need  created in ActionsViewController, also I run this method further in my app.

Comment: Then you should look at refactoring that code out into a helper, not adding a relationship between classes that otherwise wouldn't need it.